# Inverting the Merge function in Excel

Tags: excel, merge, split, rows

I am not interested in breaking text in a cell into multiple cells. I instead want to break up an empty cell into a column of cells that sits parallel to a single cell with Data.

I have an existing document with a column of cells with text descriptions. I want to turn the cell to the right of each of these into a column of 5 cells. The purpose of that is so 4 members of a group can score the text and 5th cell can average the score.

Does Excel have any options that allow for this?

One work around I see is to manually insert 4 cells under every initial cell and then merging only some of the cells. If that is the way to go, is there a way to automate that procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest just using the five cells next to the text description (in the same row).  You should be able to get the "look" you want with formatting.  I recommend against merging cells since merged cells can be difficult to deal with.

Comment: I set up a worksheet according to your description (but without merging cells). It could also have been done by merging Five cells in a column for the description, and having the scoring cells in the adjacent column.  If you need to have this kind of display, I would strongly recommend utilizing a user form for data entry, in order to minimize the chances for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of format below is what you are looking for, it can attained either by merging cells A2:A6 and A7:A11, or just by formatting the fill color and borders.

[image]